# Get flutter and package version from code

Tags: flutter, dart, logging, makefile, version

I need the flutter version and package versions for logging purposes.Is there any way to get this from flutter code or using flutter api's rather than makefile.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Dart and Flutter version within the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60581350/how-to-get-dart-and-flutter-version-within-the-app)

Comment: No @ibhavikmakwana the answer suggests to run a script but script needs to be run separately.I am looking for a solution to get these info at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Use [package_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus) package.

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();


PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();

String appName = packageInfo.appName;
String packageName = packageInfo.packageName;
String version = packageInfo.version;
String buildNumber = packageInfo.buildNumber;
```

Comment: thx! but this gives the app version not the flutter version.