# How to output Flutter version and branch from app into the console (on Flutter web)

Tags: flutter, logging, version

I need to log on the console the Flutter version and branch under which the app is currently running. I don't want the app version, but the Flutter version, for example, `Flutter 3.0.3 stable channel` or however it would output from Flutter doctor.

Is there any way I can do this? Thank you

Edit: I need to do this on Flutter web. I can get `Platform` from `dart:html` but it does not have a `version` parameter

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63417082/14388778

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Dart and Flutter version within the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60581350/how-to-get-dart-and-flutter-version-within-the-app)

Comment: @Piotr the question is for web, I don't know if that will apply

Comment: There is an open proposal on github https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61814

Comment: I edited the question to state that it was for web